# How do I print out the first instance of duplicates in an array of randomly generated numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, joptionpane

I've printed 10 random numbers in the range 20-50 while storing them in an array. I'm having trouble getting the duplicates found to work. If there's an instance in the array where there's a duplicate found, I'm trying to print out the position where it was found, not the subscript.

For example:

46

24

46

48

44

20

24

46

44

27

First pair of duplicates were found at positions: 1 and 3

Is the output that I'm trying to achieve if there's duplicates and then the same except "No duplicates were generated." if there wasn't any.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class sheet11t1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String results = "";
        int numbers[] = new int[10];
        int j;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 31) + 20);
            results += i + "\n";
        }
        boolean duplicateFound = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1 && !duplicateFound; i++)
        {
            for(j = i + 1; j < numbers.length && !duplicateFound; j++)
            {
                if(numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                    duplicateFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(duplicateFound)
                results += "First pair of duplicates were found at positions: " + numbers[i + 1] + " and " + numbers[j + 1];
        else
                results += "No duplicates were generated.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, results);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tag the programming language you are using, in this case I assume it should be java.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to add java. Thanks!

Comment: btw in your example above, what if in the case you have more than 2 numbers that are duplicated? would you show both? by using your example 46 appear 3 times and 44 appear twice.

Comment: I'm just printing the first instance where a duplicate is found, I'm not looking for all the duplicates.

Comment: Started writing a good answer to find all the duplicates. Useless now :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to change is the showing of the numbers instead of the index. so for your first loop, change to numbers[i] instead of just i. 
secondly, In your case of exiting the loop, the i and j are +1, thus when you want to print the index, you just need to specify i and j.
below is the codes.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String results = "";
    int numbers[] = new int[10];
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 31) + 20);
        results += numbers[i] + "\n";
    }
    boolean duplicateFound = false;
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1 && !duplicateFound; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < numbers.length && !duplicateFound; j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                duplicateFound = true;
        }
    }
    if(duplicateFound)
            results += "First pair of duplicates were found at positions: " + (i) + " and " + (j);
    else
            results += "No duplicates were generated.";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, results);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare both `i` and `j` outside your for loops for that approach to work. Also, you print `numbers[i+1]` and `numbers[j+1]`, which i guess should be just `i+1` and `j+1` if you want to print the 1-based positions in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- Your if check for whether duplicate is found or not is outside the loop. You should bring them inside.
- Once you set duplicateFound boolean, you never reset it. So you would just get one match only. So you might need to reset that as well.
- You are using number[i+1 or j+1], which should be i+1 or j+1 in your result string formation.

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1 && !duplicateFound; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < numbers.length && !duplicateFound; j++) {
          if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
              duplicateFound = true;
          }
          if (duplicateFound) {
              results += "pair of duplicates were found at positions: "
                      + (i + 1) + " and " + (j + 1) + "\n";
              duplicateFound = false;
          }
      }
  }
  if (results.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No duplicates were generated.");
  } else {
      System.out.println(results);
  }
  ```

There are further scope of improvement like you don't need duplicateFound variable and no further checks i.e. if further setting and resetting variable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change printing numbers using numbers[i + 1], numbers[j + 1] to i & j values

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String results = "";
    int numbers[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 31) + 20);
        results += (i + 1) + " --- " + numbers[i] + "\n";
    }

    boolean duplicateFound = false;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (; i < numbers.length - 1 && !duplicateFound; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < numbers.length && !duplicateFound; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
                duplicateFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (duplicateFound) {
        results += "First pair of duplicates were found at positions: " + i + " and " + j;
    } else {
        results += "No duplicates were generated.";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, results);
}
```